# OOm - cannot run StyleGAN2 despite reducing batch size

Tags: tensorflow, gpu

I am trying to run [StyleGAN2](https://github.com/NVlabs/stylegan2) using a cluster equipped with eight GPUs (NVIDIA GeForce RTX 2080). At present, I am using the following configuration in `training_loop.py`:

```
minibatch_size_dict     = {4: 512, 8: 256, 16: 128, 32: 64, 64: 32},       # Resolution-specific overrides.
minibatch_gpu_base      = 8,        # Number of samples processed at a time by one GPU.
minibatch_gpu_dict      = {},       # Resolution-specific overrides.
G_lrate_base            = 0.001,    # Learning rate for the generator.
G_lrate_dict            = {},       # Resolution-specific overrides.
D_lrate_base            = 0.001,    # Learning rate for the discriminator.
D_lrate_dict            = {},       # Resolution-specific overrides.
lrate_rampup_kimg       = 0,        # Duration of learning rate ramp-up.
tick_kimg_base          = 4,        # Default interval of progress snapshots.
tick_kimg_dict          = {4:10, 8:10, 16:10, 32:10, 64:10, 128:8, 256:6, 512:4}): # Resolution-specific overrides.
```

I am training using a set of 512x52 pixel images. After a couple of iterations, I get the error message reported below and it looks like the script stops running (using `watch nvidia-smi`, we have that both the temperature and the fan activity for the GPUs decreases). I already reduced the batch size but it looks like the problem is somewhere else. Do you have any tip on how to fix this?

I was able to run StyleGAN with the same dataset. In the paper they say that StyleGAN2 should be less heavy, so I am a bit surprised.

Here is the error message I get:

```
2019-12-16 18:22:54.909009: E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:828] failed to allocate 334.11M (350338048 bytes) from device: CUDA_ERROR_OUT_OF_MEMORY: out of memory
2019-12-16 18:22:54.909087: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:314] Allocator (GPU_0_bfc) ran out of memory trying to allocate 129.00MiB (rounded to 135268352).  Current allocation summary follows.
2019-12-16 18:22:54.918750: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:319] **_***************************_*****x****x******xx***_******************************_***************
2019-12-16 18:22:54.918808: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1502] OP_REQUIRES failed at conv_grad_input_ops.cc:903 : Resource exhausted: OOM when allocating tensor with shape[4,128,257,257] and type float on /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 by allocator GPU_0_bfc
```

Comment: I'm seeing the same type of error:, I've put my notes here if you want to see what I've tried so far: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/74666/is-it-possible-to-train-stylegan2-with-a-custom-dataset-using-a-graphics-card-th

Comment: Did you recently downgrade from tensorflow 2.0 to version 1.15?

Comment: What's your minibatch_size_base?

Answer (score 2):

The config-f model for StyleGAN2 is actually bigger than StyleGAN1. Try using a less VRAM consuming configuration like config-e. You can actually change the configuration of the model by passing a flag in your python command like so: https://github.com/NVlabs/stylegan2/blob/master/run_training.py#L144

In my case, I'm able to train StyleGAN2 with config-e on 2 RTX 2080ti.

Answer (score 1):

> One or more high-end NVIDIA GPUs, NVIDIA drivers, CUDA 10.0 toolkit
>   and cuDNN 7.5. To reproduce the results reported in the paper, you
>   need an NVIDIA GPU with at least 16 GB of DRAM.

Your NVIDIA GeForce RTX 2080 card has 11GB, but I guess you're saying you have 8 of them? I don't think tensorflow is setup for parallelism out of the box.

Comment: Correct, eight is the number of cards, not the memory in GB of mine ;-)

Comment: I don't think the stylegan2 code you're using is written to run on multiple GPUs.